# C# method return versus variable in a lambda

Tags: c#, variables, methods, lambda

So I was fighting some LINQ (entity framework) lambda which I ultimately fixed by storing the result in a variable. Something like:

```
IQueryable<object> DoStuff() { return /* some linq query */; }

void Main()
{
    var result = DoStuff();
    // (_database is DbContext) == true

    // Works fine
    _database.Table.Where(x => result.Contains(x.Id));

    // Throws "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '[...] DoStuff()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."
    _database.Table.Where(x => DoStuff().Contains(x.Id));
}
```

I was able to solve my problem (by accident) by just storing the query in a separate variable but I am curious as to *why* that works? Is this a deferred execution thing? Before this, I always thought that the two where exchangeable (method vs intermediate variable usage) for reference types but obviously they are not.

Comment: *What* were you fighting? What was wrong with the original code?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I started with the line that threw the exception and couldn't understand why. I think it took me two hours of fiddling and the help of a colleague to reach the solution by accident.

Comment: A downvote because?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure - it's a matter of understanding what happens to the lambda expression.

For LINQ to SQL, EF etc, it's converted into an [*expression tree*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) - basically data that represents the code in the lambda expression. The LINQ provider then has to convert that data into SQL. How can you turn a call to `DoStuff()` into SQL? You can't, because `DoStuff()` doesn't exist within the database, and the provider doesn't know what the method does to try to emulate it within SQL itself. The very limited set of method calls that *do* work are effectively hard-coded into the LINQ provider, along with the translations into SQL.

In *theory*, a particular smart LINQ provider could spot the call to `DoQuery`, analyze the IL within it to work out what it does, and check whether it understands everything within it, and convert it to SQL. I don't know any LINQ provider which does this, however, and I'd be quite surprised to see one which can do it reliably including further method calls within `DoStuff`. It would be a mammoth amount of work, and you wouldn't want it to happen at execution time anyway. (It would be awesome to see as a proof of concept, of course...)

Now, even with LINQ to Objects you'd have different behaviour between your two pieces of code. In the working code, `DoStuff()` is executed *once*, then the result used for a comparison against each element in the sequence. In the failing code, you'd be calling `DoStuff()` once *per element* in the sequence. It would still work, but you could end up executing queries multiple times unnecessarily. Note that here the transformation of the lambda expression is different - the compiler will use a *delegate* conversion instead of an expression tree conversion.

In your particular case, there may be even more going on - because your method returns `IQueryable<object>`, it's highly likely that what's returned from the method won't even have executed as a query yet - but assuming it's a LINQ query against the same database with the same provider, the LINQ provider will "understand" the query returned by `DoStuff()` and work out one SQL query including both the query part in `DoStufF()` and the use of it in `Main`. Have a look at the logs of what SQL is being executed to validate this.

Comment: Great answer (how could I expect anything else...)! Exactly the amount of technical detail I was searching for. What I take away from this is that I should always store "linq method" results in a separate variable before using them in another lambda. Now if you'll excuse me, I'll be reading up on expression trees.

Answer (score 9):

In LINQ to SQL, EF, etc., the lambda in the `Where()` method is transformed into an SQL query before it is executed. If you use own methods, this transformation fails, because the method `DoStuff()` is not known in SQL. If you get the result "outside" the LINQ lambda, then the SQL query is created with a static value and thus works...

Comment: Am i seeing this right? is this answer scoring higher than Jon's? :\ (not that this is a bad answer, far from it. just amazed, that's all)

Comment: @TimothyGroote Why are you so surprised?

Comment: Good answer! Very to the point. I was looking for some more thorough technical background on this issue so I'm afraid Jon's answer has my preference. There's worse people to lose a vote to I guess ;-)